# Many-to-many object fileds not mapped to object

Tags: go, many-to-many, go-gorm

I'm having trouble attaching related data to a model object with GORM. My setup is as follows.

```
type Domain struct {
      Id      uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;column:id"`
      Name    string    `gorm:"type:varchar(200);column:name"`
      Systems []System  `gorm:"many2many:domain_system"`
  }
  
  func (Domain) TableName() string {
      return "domain"
  }
  
  type System struct {
      Id      uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;column:id"`
      Name    string    `gorm:"type:varchar(200);column:name"`
      Domains []Domain  `gorm:"many2many:domain_system"`
  }
  
  func (System) TableName() string {
      return "system"
  }
```

than i use this function to print a `Domain` with its `Systems`

```
func ReadDomain(db *gorm.DB) {
    var domain Domain
    var systems []System

    db.Model(&domain).Related(&systems, "Systems")
    error := db.Preload("Systems").Where("id = ?", "29C6E75B-5DF0-4AA5-B6B8-6CCBA6FD8A06").Find(&domain).Error

    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println(error)
    }

    fmt.Println(domain)
}
```

and the result is

`{5be7c629-f05d-a54a-b6b8-6ccba6fd8a06 Domain 1 []}`

but it should have 3 related `Systems` instead of `[]`

The problem doesn't seem to be from the data, you can see it from the image below

[State of the database - very simple, take a look] https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIBEv.png

What am I missing, I think its something with the naming mapping, but it's a just guess?

Comment: Your data may be inside `systems` variable

Comment: ```systems``` is empty as well